# how to display an MVC View's path in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

It is extremely common for my views to have similar names but vary only by their parent directory (which is the name of the controller). In other words, I use the default patterns handed to us by the benevolent MVC overlords.

I've always found it annoying to see 3 different tabs named `List.cshtml`, however. I would rather see `Employee\List.cshtml`, `Product\List.cshtml`, etc.

Somehow, today, I got this very desired result in Visual Studio, but I have no friggin idea how I did it. Opening any other view results in only showing the file name. So, how the hell can I do this regularly and consistently?

It doesn't have anything to do with the active tab. I'm using VS2013 Ultimate. I do not have Powertools or Web Essentials installed right now but would be willing to if it meant I could see the tab on the left all the time.

FWIW, I closed the Move.cshtml tab and when I opened it back up the path disappeared.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Well. I now remember what was different about that file... my computer crashed (BSOD) and Visual Studio asked me if I wanted to recover my changes to Move.cshtml. That has to be why it is there. I am disappoint.